# ImageMagick media conversion exceptions

Tags: java, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

We are getting a few exceptions when we try to convert an image on a Linux box. When we try the same media conversion on a Windows 8 machine it works perfectly, without any exceptions.

The same version is being used on both the Linux and Windows machines: ImageMagick 6.7.3-5

Please find the exceptions below:

> [MediaConversionJob] Failed to convert container 'MediaContainerModel (8797477011506)' for format '8796093382707'.
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/10/09 22:21:55.781 | [0;31mERROR [pool-1-thread-16] (xxTuProductMediaConversionCronjobMultiThreadUnscheduled) [DefaultImageMagickService] convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/NFS_DATA/hybris-media/sys_master/cache/products/h51/hab/c3lzLW1hc3Rlci9wcm9kdWN0cy9oMjYvaGIyLzg4MjEwMzk3NTkzOTAvMTI2NjU2MzgwX05hdnlfMDEuanBn__H__b7457ad8-4ad6-4777-824f-4a0d6ddb48fc.bin' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/533.
>
> INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/10/09 22:21:55.781 | [m[0;31mERROR [pool-1-thread-16] (xxTuProductMediaConversionCronjobMultiThreadUnscheduled) [DefaultImageMagickService] convert: missing an image filename `/opt/hybris_tu/temp/hybris/convert/tmp_3568635358706829874.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2940.

Is it a version problem?

Comment: Try this command for listing the installed delegates (i.e formats supported) `convert -list configure | grep 'DELEGATES'`

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/ and install the decode delegate that is missing.